# Assign 2 IP addresses to one virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virsh

I would like to assign 2 IP addresses to one virtual machine but cannot make it working. I have

```
IP              MAC
151.180.39.138   02:aa:cc:73:b1:39
78.132.120.30   02:cc:aa:79:fb:e7
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 151.180.39.138
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 151.180.39.138
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-search server3
        pre-up ifconfig eth0 hw ether 02:aa:cc:73:b1:39
        post-up route add 137.159.142.254 dev eth0
        post-up route add default gw 137.159.142.254
        pre-down route del 137.159.142.254 dev eth0
        pre-down route del default gw 137.159.142.254

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
       address 78.132.120.30
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       broadcast 78.132.120.30
       dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
       post-up route add 137.159.142.254 dev eth1
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:aa:cc:73:b1:39  
          inet addr:151.180.39.138  Bcast:151.180.39.138  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ff:fe73:b139/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6121 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:993 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:487116 (487.1 KB)  TX bytes:141802 (141.8 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:cc:aa:79:fb:e7  
          inet addr:78.132.120.30  Bcast:78.132.120.30  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ff:fe79:fbe7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5225 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:409486 (409.4 KB)  TX bytes:1066 (1.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1822 (1.8 KB)  TX bytes:1822 (1.8 KB)
```

I have two interfaces in config file and when I do virsh edit server3 I can see

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='02:aa:cc:73:b1:39'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='02:cc:aa:79:fb:e7'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

How to make it working so I can access both IP addresses as currently 2nd is not accessible.

Comment: What is this? Why are you using two virtual NICs? They even seem to be on the same bridge. You only need one.

Comment: Probably you are missing the routing to get to the second NIC. Can you please paste the output of running `ip r` in the hypervisor? That will list the routing in your hypervisor.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am trying to attach 2 IP addresses to 1 virtual machine but not sure if I am doing it correctly, do you know how this could be achieved?

Comment: Based on whois, these 3 ip addresses are assigned to three different companies/organizations. Are you sure these three are back correct and assigned to your server? Can you post the network config of the hypervisor?